# Probability that a sample belongs to distribution

Tags: probability

Let's assume I have a system that takes an input and has a measurable output. I have a collection of samples taken from an experiment $(i,o)$ where $i$ is the input and $o$ is the output. From this set of measurements, I approximate the parameters $\theta$ for fitting a specific distribution (let's assume Normal).

Over the time, I take measurements from the system i.e. $(i_q,o_q)$. I want to check if the system is still functioning as before. To check that I figured that I could find the probability that the sample $(i_q,o_q)$ belongs to the previously observed distribution with parameters $\theta$. Is this approach correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It of course depends on how confident you are in your initial "population" distribution, but yes, this is the general idea.

I would first check your guess on the distribution family using Kolmogorov-Smirnov or Anderson-Darling, but after you have a distribution and estimates that you trust describe the data as it stood at time $t_0$, checking the probability of observing the new observation under the originally estimated distribution is about all you can do if you don't want to get into implementing some complicated Bayesian online learning method. Also, if you are testing if a new $set$ of observations (a new sample) is from the original distribution, you can use any number of methods (including the two methods I mention above -- I would take a close look at the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test in particular).